# Host an api from local file

Tags: python, api, rest, hosting

To start: I'm new in the area of hosting and api's!

Lets say I have a JSON file containing my local time(which is updated every second), I have an api (I think) running locally using Flask. How can I make this api publicly accessible and still have it updated every few seconds at least. I hope I explained it properly;)

Thanks in advance!!

ps: I have the python script locally running and updating the file, this python script can only be run local, not by any hosting service.

Comment: By publicly accessible, do you mean accessible from the internet? Do you have a static dedicated IP from your ISP?

Comment: yes publicly accessible, so anyone in the world can make a call to the api.

Comment: To basically replicate something like this: http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone , I already have the data, but now need it to be an api.

Comment: Ok, first of all, they don't actually have a file they update every second, their webserver simply return a JSON serialization of a data calculated from their server time. Secondly, this is something that you'd want to host on actual web server instead, there are plenty of cheap and even free options out there, you won't have to bother with maintaining the security and reliability of your server

Comment: If you *do* insist on hosting locally, then you'll need to acquire a static dedicated IP from your ISP, getting them to open port 80 & 443 if you want the API available without ugly port number in every call. If you can't get a static IP, but the port is open, then you'd want to setup a DDNS, your API will be unavailable for a minute or so if the IP changes. Then you'd need to learn about configuring your router forwarding, your OS firewall, securing your OS and web server apps, keeping them updated etc